# Is Python re thread-safe?

Tags: python, regex

I tried googling but gotten no authoritative answer.

Can someone confirm that the `re` module http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
is thread-safe?

More specifically, which functions are and which are not?

Also, can I reuse a single global compiled re object to do `sub`, `search`, etc. safely across threads?

**Seems like there is still no clear answer?**

Ok, a more specific example:

```
  class MyClass:
     GLOBAL_VAR = re.compile(...)

     def clean(self, value):
        return MyClass.GLOBAL_VAR.sub('', value)
```

Will this work as expected when multiple threads call clean at the same time?

Comment: I think you might want to read http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock. Python (at least CPython which is most common interpreter) does not really benefit from multiple threads (except when doing I/O bound operations).

Comment: @elmo: The GIL doesn't make Python libraries thread-safe. [`regex` module (backward-compatible with `re` module) may release GIL i.e., you *can* utilize multiple CPUs using threads](https://gist.github.com/zed/0bc1c1edd4fb61a985ff).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: true, though I would expect all libraries to behave sanely (especially standard ones). If they release GIL that means they know what they are doing (are thread-safe). So I would assume that in fact everything is thread-safe (if it's not I would consider it a bug), because of GIL. Note that those are my **assumptions** based on my still limited knowledge of Python, so do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @elmo: I've mentioned the releasing of GIL by `regex` module only to show that Python *may* really benefit from multiple threads (even when doing CPU bound operations). It is orthogonal to the question of thread-safety. Everything is *not* thread-safe unless module docs say so or you've inspected the source code and proved that your usage of the implementation is thread-safe. To be fair, stdlib modules are rarely documented as thread-safe even though there are usage patterns that allow to use the modules safely from multiple threads without any additional synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there *is* an authoritative answer—other than digging around in the source, which gets you answers for existing versions of Python but not necessarily future ones—since at least some parts of some versions of the regular expression module are written in C (at least for CPython; for Jython, for instance, who knows?) and nobody seems to have made any promises about them.

In practice I have not seen any bits of the RE code that are *not* thread-safe, and your later example with the `GLOBAL_VAR.sub` call is "almost certainly" thread-safe.  But ... there's still that darned lack of written promises. :-)

Comment: I just store the compiled version myself.  I wish the documentation would promise thread-safety though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, They are thread safe, Because there is just a _cache dictionary between functions, each functions will use it to look up the generated value, and if the value was not in _cache, functions will generate value and put it to the _cache dictionary, and it won't violate the thread safety

Comment: I don't follow. Integers are immutable (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). So let's say a module has a global `i = 1`, and a method `incr()` that does `i = i + 1`. Now two calls to `incr()` should set `i` to `3`. But if called via different threads, you could end up with `i = 2` (in case both threads read the value of `i` when it was still `1`). So, you got only immutable objects, but this is not thread safe.

Comment: @Mr.E. Still your module is not immutable. the module will change during work by a thread

Comment: @Mr.E. The entire complex operation of adding and substitution is not thread-safe. The question is not really good, because it is very easy to give an example of non thread-safe code using `re` like for example setting a global to some RegexObject and then reading it (that would be the same as your example). However as Pooya pointed out it is not possible to do that inside one RegexObject. That's also true for integers. They are thread-safe as well. What is not thread-safe is operations involving more then one integer.

Comment: @freakish: my example was just to show that you cannot state that a module is thread safe simply *"because all functions and objects are immutable"*, as it is mentioned on the answer.

Comment: @Mr.E. There is no shared variable or parameters between functions of re module

Comment: You are wrong. http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/re.py. Search for `_cache`.

Comment: @Mr.E.: [there is shared cache](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/re.py#l262) though it shouldn't affect any results

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, I agree, it *shouldn't* (and probably doesn't, if you look at the implementation) affect anything. But it is a shared `dict`; without looking at the source, you couldn't be sure.

Comment: @Mr.E. If the cache with given key was None, so the thread will regenerate the value and put it in the _cache dict. So still it is thread safe

Comment: @Mr.E. I'm not wrong, this _cache dict did not effect on any states or values of the module

Comment: *"There is no shared variable or parameters between functions of re module"* == False!!

Comment: @Mr.E. Ok, But you said the module is not immutable, And I mean there is nothing to violate the thread safety of this module

Comment: Pooya, I too believe it to be thread safe, but the point is 1) it has nothing to do with immutability (therefore your answer might be correct but the reasoning is wrong) and 2) you could only give an "authoritative" answer by looking at the complete source code.